# Convert a square pandas dataframe to a tall format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is a correlation matrix. I want to create a graph out of it and to do so I need to convert the correlation dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0.2,0.4],[0.2,1,0.6],[0.4,0.6,1]])
df.columns = list('ABC')
df.index= list('ABC')
df

# result- 

     A    B    C
A  1.0  0.2  0.4
B  0.2  1.0  0.6
C  0.4  0.6  1.0
```

to this format -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'to':['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'value':[1, 0.2,0.4,1,0.6,1]})
df

# result- 
  from to  value
0    A  A    1.0
1    A  B    0.2
2    A  C    0.4
3    B  B    1.0
4    B  C    0.6
5    C  C    1.0
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().rename_axis(('from','to')).reset_index(name='value')
print (df1)
  from to  value
0    A  A    1.0
1    A  B    0.2
2    A  C    0.4
3    B  A    0.2
4    B  B    1.0
5    B  C    0.6
6    C  A    0.4
7    C  B    0.6
8    C  C    1.0
```

Another numpy solution:

```
a = np.repeat(df.columns, len(df.index))
b = np.tile(df.index, len(df.columns))
c = df.values.ravel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from':a, 'to':b, 'value':c})
print (df1)

  from to  value
0    A  A    1.0
1    A  B    0.2
2    A  C    0.4
3    B  A    0.2
4    B  B    1.0
5    B  C    0.6
6    C  A    0.4
7    C  B    0.6
8    C  C    1.0
```

EDIT:

Another solution for remove duplicates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0.2,0.4],[0.2,1,0.6],[0.4,0.6,1]])
df.columns = list('ACC')
df.index= list('ABC')
print (df)
     A    C    C
A  1.0  0.2  0.4
B  0.2  1.0  0.6
C  0.4  0.6  1.0

a = np.repeat(df.columns, len(df.index))
b = np.tile(df.index, len(df.columns))
c = df.values.ravel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'from':a, 'to':b, 'value':c})

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1[['from','to']], axis=1), columns=['from','to'])
        .drop_duplicates())
print (df1)

  from to
0    A  A
1    A  B
2    A  C
4    B  C
5    C  C
```

Comment: that was quick. Thanks

Comment: The numpy solution looks off. The columns `from` and `to` columns are the same

Comment: yeah looks good now. I have self-posted an answer based on the solution you provided

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted jezrael's answer. For sake of completeness, I am adding a couple of lines to remove the duplicates.

```
# from jezrael's solution
df1 = df.stack().rename_axis(('from','to')).reset_index(name='value')

# drop the dupes
df1.loc[:, ['from', 'to']] = df1.loc[:, ['from', 'to']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df1.drop_duplicates()
# result -
  from to
0    A  A
1    A  B
2    A  C
4    B  B
5    B  C
8    C  C
```